# Why does `top` return immediately in eshell?

Tags: emacs, eshell

Can eshell run top command interactively as  other shell does ?

Regards!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be out of luck. See [here](http://www.masteringemacs.org/articles/2010/12/13/complete-guide-mastering-eshell/).

> Despite all the advantages offered by Eshell, there are some points I
>   want to make that seem to confuse some people:
>
> 1. Eshell does not support interactive (or “visual” in Eshell parlance)
>      programs, like `top`, directly; you must tell Eshell to launch them in a
>      separate `ansi-term` instance instead.